# In MVC, How can I develop something like the old school User Control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, user-controls

I have a TreeView, wish is used to display some hierarchy. Also, I have some behaviors implemented, such as if the collapsed nodes will be opened when the parent is checked, or if it's lazy loading or will load everything automatically. But I don't want to let these behaviors hard coded. I want to create a customizable control. Something like Telerik Kendo UI does. They have a control developed, that can be used like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox()
    .Name("phone_number")
    .Mask("(999) 000-0000")
    .Value("555 123 4567")
)
```

Notice that you can pass some options to it.
Also, I want to be able to pass the name of the action that will populate my TreeView using async. So, if I use this component at, for example, mysite/myController/indexAction, I want to pass a name of the action who will populate my component asynchronous. Let's exemplify. I want something like this:

```
@(Html.Foo().HierarchyView()
    .Name("myTree")
    .AllowCheckBoxes(true)
    .PopulateChildrenOnCheck(true)
    .Async("GetChildrenAsync")
)
```

So, I can implement at myController an action

```
string GetChildrenAsync(int idKey) {
    var nodes = new List<HierarchViewNodes>();
    (...) //implementation to populate the children nodes
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodes);
}
```

So, it would be an start for my customizable control. Of course I can extend it a lot.
I've searched and learned about RenderPartial and RenderAction, but I can't figure out yet how I can fully use it to make really reusable controls like the one I explained.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at making some [custom HTML helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs). For example, yours might look something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTreeView(this HtmlHelper html, params...){
    var myHtmlContent = ....;
    // .. implement your functionality and generate the html to put in your view
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(myHtmlContent);
}
```

and you could use it in your Razor view like this:

```
<div>@Html.MyTreeView(params...)</div>
```

That is a very simple example, but hopefully it puts you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you rwisch45. Indeed, a custom HTMLHelper might be the best approach. I'm implementing it, but I'm using @ALMMa answer, because I want to create something like a library of custom components, and his approach will let things a little more organized. Thank you anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest some HTML extensions, as rwisch45 said, but protected (and organized) within a separate "sub-helper", like Kendo and DevExpress:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
   public static static MyCustomHelper CustomHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
   {
      return new MyCustomHelper(htmlHelper);
   }
}

public class MyCustomHelper
{
   HtmlHelper _HtmlHelper;
   public MyCustomHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper) { _HtmlHelper = htmlHelper; }

   public MvcHtmlString WriteSomethingInteresting(string value)
   { return new MvcHtmlString(value); }

   public MyCustomGrid CreateMyGrid(object gridOptions)
   {
      // I won't show now how to transform dynamic into type.
      // You can find that on SO quite easy.
      var typedOptions = TransformDynamicIntoClass<GridOptions>(gridOptions);

      return new MyCustomGrid(typedOptions);
   }
}

public class MyCustomGrid : IHtmlString
{
   public string ToHtmlString()
   {
      // Return your grid as an HTML object!
   }
}
```

This way you'll have:

```
@Html.CustomHelper().MyCustomGrid(new { Option1 = "", Option2 = "", ...... });
```

You may, however, play a little with IDisposable, to have something like:

```
@using(Html.CustomHelper().MyCustomGrid(....))
{
   // Dunno what could come here for a grid (poor sample) but maybe for a pane helper?
}
```

Comment: Hi @ALMMa, I'm trying your approach. I think it doesn't exist the interface IMvcHtmlString on the framework. I'm trying to implement the interface IHtmlSting. Do you think it will work?
It couldn't render my scripts well. I don't know if it's because I have to return an MVCHTMLString and not a pure string (that overriding ToHtmlSting method from IHtmlString interface will do).
Do you know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. It's `IHtmlString`. Updated my answer. By *not working* do you mean that the resulting text is rendered *as-is* instead of valid HTML elements?

Comment: As it's returned as a pure string, if I have something like:
<script src='path.js'></script>
I have an access error: Not allowed to load local resource.
I think it's a security issue.

Comment: Placing exactly the same call (eg: `src='path.js'`) within the view works fine?

Comment: Yes, placing it in the view makes things work. So, I can go with 2 options:
1) when use this helper, let it clear that a reference for certain .js and .css must be done at the view that is calling the user control, or
2) study and implement a method that will let a script or a style be referenced inside the user control without the not allowed problem.
I'll do some researches and let you know which approach I take here.